# couldn't open output file: Read-only file system

Tags: command-line, permissions, python, filesystem, gnome-terminal

I just installed Ubuntu. My problem is I am attempting to write a log file to home. I am using `logcat` from a python module called `adb`. When I attempt the terminal command `adb logcat -f <path>` I should be able to output this log to a text file on my hard drive, but Instead I get the error:

```
couldn't open output file: Read-only file system
```

This is despite attempting the command `sudo adb logcat -f <path>`.
For `<path>` I have mainly been trying just 'log' and 'log.txt'

I am able to write files to disk using `cat >` and I can save files without issue. I have read that this can be caused by a failing hard disk, but up until now I haven't seen any other evidence of this. Any help in understanding why this is happening and how to overcome it would be greatly appreciated. In case anyone is wondering, it *is* necessary for me to output this file to disk.

**EDIT:**

I should mention that I did in fact have a problem with my swap partition. I was getting an error to the tune of `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present`(not exact wording)on the splash screen during boot, but I reformatted and made a new swap partition which got rid of the error. However, both before seeing to the problem, and still now, gparted labels the swap partition as 'unknown'. `free -m` shows no issues, nor does `swapon -s`

**EDIT:** output of `sudo mount`

```
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda7 on /home type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
/home/me/.Private on /home/me type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=cbb0ed41b9f457c5,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=9e985b7d47d6e940)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=me)
```

output of `apt-cache policy 'sytemd*'`:

```
Version table:
 *** 204-0ubuntu19.1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     204-0ubuntu18 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
root-system-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.34.09-1
  Version table:
     5.34.09-1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
libboost-filesystem1.50-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-data4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
qemu-system-or32:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
xen-system:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system2.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libsystemu-ruby1.8:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.5.1-1
  Version table:
     2.5.1-1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
system-image-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.9.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
libsystemsettings1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.1+13.10.20131015.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.1+13.10.20131015.2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
xen-linux-system-686-pae:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
ubuntu-system-service:
  Installed: 0.2.5
  Candidate: 0.2.5
  Version table:
 *** 0.2.5 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
qemu-system-s390x:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libboost-filesystem1.53.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8
  Version table:
     1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
qemu-system-ppcemb:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
systemc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
system-config-printer:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
systemd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
qemu-system-sh4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
xen-linux-system-amd64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
qemu-system-xtensa:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libghc-system-fileio-prof-0.3.10-17c22:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libghc-system-filepath-prof:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.7-2build1
  Version table:
     0.4.7-2build1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
libqtsysteminfo1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.0-3ubuntu5
  Version table:
     1.2.0-3ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
system-tools-backends-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.10.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
libboost-system1.52-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
system-config-samba:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.63-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
     1.2.63-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
libmono-system-security4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libboost-filesystem1.46-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libghc-filesystem-conduit-doc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.0-2build1
  Version table:
     1.0.0-2build1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
root-system-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.34.09-1
  Version table:
     5.34.09-1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
system-config-printer-gnome:
  Installed: 1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
qemu-system-ppc64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
liblua5.1-filesystem0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.0+16+g84f1af5-1
  Version table:
     1.5.0+16+g84f1af5-1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
system-tools-backends:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.10.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
qemu-system-x86:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3
  Version table:
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
system-config-printer-kde:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
init-system-helpers:
  Installed: 1.7
  Candidate: 1.7
  Version table:
 *** 1.7 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
systemd-shim:
  Installed: 6-0ubuntu0.13.10
  Candidate: 6-0ubuntu0.13.10
  Version table:
 *** 6-0ubuntu0.13.10 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3+real-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libghc-system-fileio-doc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.10-2build1
  Version table:
     0.3.10-2build1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
systemtap-grapher:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libghc-system-filepath-dev-0.4.7-c7b27:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
qemu-system-x86-64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
system-config-printer-udev:
  Installed: 1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.2+20130920-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libsystem-command-perl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.09-1
  Version table:
     1.09-1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
libboost-system1.42-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
qemu-system:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3
  Version table:
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
systemtap-doc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.2.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libboost-system1.48-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
lua5.2-filesystem-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
system-config-kickstart:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.5.20-0ubuntu22
  Version table:
     2.5.20-0ubuntu22 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
live-config-systemd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.23-1
  Version table:
     3.0.23-1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
systemtap:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.2.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
libsystemd-login-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 204-0ubuntu19.1
  Version table:
     204-0ubuntu19.1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     204-0ubuntu18 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
x-window-system:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
qemu-system-mips64el:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libsystemu-ruby-doc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.5.1-1
  Version table:
     2.5.1-1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
xen-system-amd64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.3.0-1ubuntu1.3
  Version table:
     4.3.0-1ubuntu1.3 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     4.3.0-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
qemu-system-sparc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3
  Version table:
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
xen-linux-system-686:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
gnome-system-log:
  Installed: 3.8.1-1svn1
  Candidate: 3.8.1-1svn1
  Version table:
 *** 3.8.1-1svn1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libmono-system4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libqt5systeminfo5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0~git20130712-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     5.0~git20130712-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0~git20130712-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     5.0~git20130712-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
xen-system-i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libboost-system1.53-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8
  Version table:
     1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
qemu-system-m68k:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
qemu-system-mips:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3
  Version table:
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libfsosystem-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
qemu-system-i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
qemu-system-misc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3
  Version table:
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5.3 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.5.0+dfsg-3ubuntu5 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
libghc-system-filepath-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.7-2build1
  Version table:
     0.4.7-2build1 0
        500 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please include the actual path of your desired output file. If the path is simply `log` in your current directory, please explain which directory you are running from. Do you get the same message if you do this from your `$HOME`?

Comment: Running from HOME :)

Comment: strange, all my other comments have disappeared

Comment: Yes, comments can be deleted without warning, that's why details should always be added to the question body. Now, if I understand correctly, you only get this from a python script. Is that right? Can you run the command itself from the terminal correctly? Can we see the relevant parts of your script?

Comment: if I run 'adb logcat' then I get the desired output to the terminal, option -f <path> should output to a file. So it's working without the -f <path> bit

Comment: This is not part of a script, I just wanted the log file to troubleshoot some unrelated issues. If I just output to the terminal then too much info gets passed by

Comment: Well, you can always use `adb logcat > log` of course, are you sure the `-f` option does what you think it does? I don't know where to get this `adb` in order to test.

Comment: from adb logcat --help is the following on -f:                    -f <filename>   Log to file. Default to stdout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can simply redirect the output yourself instead of using the `-f` option:

```
adb logcat > log
```

I am guessing that the program might change it's working directory so it's trying to create  `log` somewhere where you have no write access. If so, you should also be able to get it to work using an absolute path:

```
adb logcat > /home/username/log
```